# K-centers clustering using R - is the resulting plot off?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to do `k-means` clustering using R, and this is what I have done so far:

```
tmp <- kmeans(ds, centers = 4, iter.max = 1000) 

plot(ds[tmp$cluster==1,c(1,5)], col = "red", xlim = c(min(ds[,1]),  
  max(ds[,1])), ylim = c(min(ds[,5]), max(ds[,5])))
  points(ds[tmp$cluster==2,c(1,5)], col = "blue")
  points(ds[tmp$cluster==3,c(1,5)], col = "seagreen")
  points(ds[tmp$cluster==4,c(1,5)], col = "orange")
  points(tmp$centers[,c(1,5)], col = "black")
```

and I get the following graph:

[image]

I am quite new to this, so I may be way off, but this graph does not look quite right to me. The data is basically divided in zones and to be honest, I was expecting to see something along the lines of this:

[image]

- The circles in this picture are just to showcase where I was expecting the clusters to be. Can anyone explain why the data is clustered like that? I did the clustering multiple times and I always end up with this result.

The dataset I am using can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset).

Comment: Plot the data with the same scale on x and y!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `Age` runs from about 18 to 60,  so the maximum distance between age is about 40.  Now notice that the incomes range from 0 to 20000. The distance between points is heavily dominated by the income. If you wish *both* variables to be used in the clustering, you should scale the data before clustering.    Try

```
tmp<-kmeans(scale(ds), centers = 4, iter.max = 1000)
```

Comment: Hi @G5W, thank you for the fast response. I understand where you were going with this, however when I try to plot it, the clusters make even less sense, since they completely overlap one another https://i.gyazo.com/ccccdb21300aa0aa577efcf0f7e3d1ed.png

Comment: @AnnaP  If they overlap,  you are making a mistake. Can you provide your data?  If you can,  please add it to your question.  Use `dput(ds)`to make a text version for the question.

Comment: I included a link to my dataset @G5W

Comment: @AnnaP.   Unfortunately,  your link only works if you have a kaggle account,   which I do not.   Can you do   `dput(ds)` and add it to ypur question?

Comment: the page crashes every time I try to add it, would a link to a google drive doc be alright? @G5W

Comment: @AnnaP. If it does not require a password.

Comment: @AnnaP. Unfortunately, that too is asking for a password (sign in to Google drive)

Comment: Yeah I saw, I'll just do some further research on my own and hopefully figure things out. Thank you so very much for all your help and for spending so much time on this! @G5W

Answer (score 2):

This is how the k-means clustering algorithm work. Google "k-means clustering" and look at the picture results and you will see different variations: circular clusters and the type you received. If you set number of clusters *k* to a different number, you will get different clusters. The goal of the algorithm is to partition a data set into a desired number of non-overlapping clusters *k*, so that the total *within-cluster variation* is minimized. And this is the result you see in your plot.

Comment: You are right, there are examples online like my graph, I should have paid attention to the fact that the income scales up so high compared to the age. Thank you for the help!